# Is it possible to include a pdf image into a xaringan presentation?

Tags: r, xaringan

xaringan is great! However i do not seem to manage to include a pdf image into the presentation via

```
![](filename.pdf)
```

or via `knitr::include_graphics`. Is this somehow possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `magick` package to convert a page into a graphic object:

````
```{r}
magick::image_read_pdf("test.pdf",
                       pages = 1)
```
````

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. It was a bit weird, the originanal .rmd file didnt show the Graphic, but creating a new .rmd file with the same syntax worked.

Comment: I would assume that something with your chunk settings is different in the original file.